# How to use swi-prolog with android

Tags: java, android, jvm, prolog, jpl

I have developed a prolog program with swi-prolog and I attached a interface for it using regular java with JPL.jar,
That is running perfectly.

Now I want do the same with android mobile interfaces instead of java desktop interfaces. So I created a android application, add the JPL as external jar and called the prolog files as earlier. There are no errors showed in the code.

But when I run it as a android application it says jpl.query$1 cannot be found.

here is the logcat

```
08-21 17:36:35.782: D/dalvikvm(659): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0cd8 at 0x08 in Ljpl/Query;.abort
08-21 17:36:35.812: W/dalvikvm(659): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Ljpl/fli/Prolog;
08-21 17:36:35.812: D/AndroidRuntime(659): Shutting down VM
08-21 17:36:35.822: W/dalvikvm(659): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at jpl.Query.open(Query.java:286)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at jpl.Util.textToTerm(Util.java:162)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at jpl.Query.<init>(Query.java:198)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.trtest.swi.main(swi.java:21)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.example.trtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
------
----

08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jpl: findLibrary returned null
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at jpl.JPL.loadNativeLibrary(JPL.java:100)
08-21 17:36:35.916: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at jpl.fli.Prolog.<clinit>(Prolog.java:85)
...
```

So what is the error could be.

I found some says that JPL(swi prolog) cannot be used in android, is that true.

What can I do to have my prolog app run on android

thanks
Mathee

Comment: You have the duplicate copy of same jar's ?

Comment: Sad to say, but SWI-Prolog cannot run in Android. We all hope it will do...

Answer (score 4):

Jan Wielemaker, SWI-Prolog developer, posted recently some progress towards using SWI-Prolog on Android devices on the mailing list. See [[SWIPL] Holiday present: SWI-Prolog on Android](https://lists.iai.uni-bonn.de/pipermail/swi-prolog/2013/010957.html)

Comment: sadly the URL is broken, as 10/8/2014

Comment: found a valid URL: http://swi-prolog.996271.n3.nabble.com/Holiday-present-SWI-Prolog-on-Android-td12798.html, which leads to the official site: http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/linuxonandroid.txt